# Why the 2 other blocks have zero acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I was doing an exercise and I was stopped after arriving to a question,

> $3$  blocks  $A$ , $B$ and $C$ are attached between them by massless and frictionless strings, that passes through frictionless, massless pulleys, the blocks $A$ and $B$ have the same weight $25\ N$ and the same coefficient of kinetic friction $0.35$ , the bloc $C$ goes down with a constant speed.
>
> I must find out the tension of the two strings.

Using Newton's 2nd law we get: $a_{C} = 0 $

because the speed is constant ,

what I can't figure out is why in the correction they said that : $ ~~a_{B}=0 ~~$    and  $~~a_{A} = 0$

Why both of block A and B have ALSO a zero acceleration , how do we know that ?

[image]

Comment: if block C is moving down with constant velocity, so is the string attached to it. Which means block B and therefore block A also moves with constant velocity

Comment: is there any mathematical way to prove it ?

Comment: Let $L$ the length of the string between B and C.  $x_C(t)$ is the position of C, $x_B(t)$ is the position of B.  then $x_C(t) = x_B(t) +L$.  Then take derivatives to find velocity and acceleration.

Comment: when you said $x_{C} (t)$ and $x_{B}(t)$  , does the $x$ represents the $x$ axis ? or the $y$ axis ? I mean what axis did you choose as reference to speak about position ???

Comment: conservation of string

Answer (score 1):

If block $C$ moves a distance $x$ (let's say) then for the string to remain taut the block $B$ has to move the same distance i.e. $x$. Which makes the block $A$ to move a distance $x$. Since this is happening in same time each block has same velocity and acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

That's a constraint from the strings, the distances between the blocks must stay the same.  If the distances became less, the strings would not be taut so could not produce tension, and if the distances became more, the strings would break.  Since the distances must stay the same, the speeds along the direction of motion have to stay the same for all 3 blocks, which means they all have the same acceleration.  That acceleration must be zero because it is for C.

Perhaps what bothers you is that this does indeed represent an idealization about the strings-- if they were replaced with rubber bands, there is a new mode of motion possible that involves an oscillation of the distances between the blocks.  So the strings are idealized as rubber bands or springs that are very stiff, i.e., have an infinite spring constant.  That's what maintains a constant distance between the blocks, it effectively means that any oscillation is of such a high frequency and low amplitude that we just average over it and replace it with zero acceleration.

Comment: but for example the bloc B could accelerate and pull with him the bloc A , without breaking the strings

Comment: If it pulls block A with some different force(i.e. other than which gives 0 acc to C) , it's gonna change speed of block C, and you don't want that!!!Right?

Comment: " the speeds along the direction of motion" we have three blocks each one moving in a different direction , what do you mean by the direction of motion ???

Comment: We are free to describe the motion in any coordinate we like.  A simple one here is the direction along the strings.  So for block A, that is horizontal, for block B, that is diagonally upward, and for block C, vertical.  Using those coordinates, each block will have the same rate of change of the coordinate, that is the requirement imposed by the strings.  That's what I mean by "the same speed along the direction of motion."

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the string attached between A and B be S¹ and that between B and C be S².
As C is moving in constant velocity so does B and hence A too, because they are connected via strings which are almost massless, hence the motion is constrained.

And now the tensions can be easily found out.

T² = T¹ + mg sin(theta) + (meu)mg cos(theta)

And T¹ = (meu) mg

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the displacement $x_b = x_c = x_a$, since the rope is same. The block B moves through same distance of as C pulls the rope downwards. Differentiate the equality twice wrt time, you'll get $a_a=a_b=a_c$ which in this case is zero.

Comment: 1- why having the same rope means that the dispacement is the same ??? 
2- if the acceleration is the same that means that the velocity is the same isn'it ? but I think that's untrue since friction is acting on A and B , which means that their velocity would be lower than  C's velocity .

Comment: No. All the displacement, velocity and acceleration are same. To understand the concept of displacement in rope, consider it as a train. If the front of train moves 1 m, the back also moves the same, since it is not stretchable.

Comment: And for friction acting on block A and B, consider brake is applied at front of train. Will the back move with different velocity, or it will also come at rest?

Comment: but in our case the brakes aren't applied in the frond , but in the back , more pricesely it's the path that A and B  were going through that causes friction because it isn't frictionless . so  if we suppose that the path was frictionless , we could imagine that they have all same speed , but since there is friction , it means that A and B will be slower  , isn'it ?

Comment: No. So long as the rope is not stretchable. If it was stretchable, you are right.

Comment: I don't know why I'am struggling with it , it makes me very confused , may be because there isn"t a mathematical way to prove it or there is but I don't know how to prove or I don't have the tools to prove it .

Comment: @Hilbert It is a **constraint relation** that we get if we assume that the string is taut and inextensible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've figured out why , since the rope is the same and it's non-strichable and has to be taut , that means that the distance between the 3 blocks will always be the same in any circumstance , wich means that if the block c moves with a distance $dx$ so do the string and do the 2 other blocks , so the three moves with the same distance $dx$ divide by time that yields the speed is the same for all of them , isn'it ?

Comment: in fact , even every piece of the rope itself has the same speed  , we can considerate the 2 ropes and the 3 blocks like one whole system that has one speed .